# What is the difference between a mixture and a composed substance?

Tags: periodic-table, mixtures

In my textbook it says, that a composed substance is a substance made of more than 1 type of atom. And It also says, in another chapter it says that a mixture is the grouping of more than one substance without any chemical reaction.

What is the difference between a mixture and a composed substance?

Answer (score 3):

From the definitions in your textbook, it seems that a mixture is a combination of two or more substances that--though combined--maintain their chemical identifiability. Examples of mixtures might be:

- Water/Alcohol Mixtures
- Salt/Pepper Mixture
- In pharmacy, pills, pastes/creams, and suppositories are mixtures

(there are many example of mixtures)

The consituent compounds might be separated with somewhat mild techniques, including dissolving in certain solvents, distillation, and crystallization.

Composed Substances (according to your textbook) are mixtures of two or more species that under go some chemical reaction. The species involved could lose most of their identifiability, becoming completely different compound(s).  Loosely speaking, chemical reactions can not be reversed by simple separation techniques.

(Of course, there is some arbitrariness here: particularly in what comprises "most" of their identifiability and what defines "simple" separation techniques.  Also, mixtures are actually held together with bonds, just like in composed substances.  They may be weaker, but even "weakness" of the interaction is a subjective concept.)

Answer (score 0):

Both composed substances and mixtures have more than type of atoms.

However, there are some difference between them both.

1)composed substances=mix chemically, mixture=mix physically

Composed substances are usually mix together through chemical process just like burning, titration and redox reaction.

While mixture are mix together through physical process like dissolving and even putting together.

2)Composed substances and mixture properties

Composed substances have different properties with it original atoms.
i.e iron sulphide do not attarct to magnet although iron is magnetic.

While mixture have the same properties with its original atoms.
i.e. a pile of iron filling and sulphur powder. The iron will still attarct to magnet and the sulphur don't

3)Bond between atoms

In composed substances, the atoms are bonded with either ionic bond or covelent bond. i.e the hydrogen and oxygen atoms in a water molecule have colevent bonds between them.

In mixture, the atoms do not bond together. i.e oxygen gas, nitrogen gas, carbon dioxide gas in the air do not have bond between them as they flows freely in the air.

They are also a lot more differences between these both such as melting point, existing states of matter, conductivity of electricity and heat etc. I hope this helps.